# how to Define a semaphore with busy waiting solution

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

How do i Define a semaphore with busy waiting solution  ??i got something like this

```
wait(Semaphore s){
s=s-1;
if (s<=0) {
    // add process to queue
    block();
}
}

signal(Semaphore s){
s=s+1;
if (s<0) {
    // remove process p from queue
    wakeup(p);
}
}
```

but i don't understand the condition required in signal block

if (s<0) {
        // remove process p from queue
        wakeup(p);
    }

why we are checking if(s<0) here

Answer (score 0):

The condition should probably detect if there is any process sleeping (blocked) in the queue. However, I think these conditions are not correct, considering behaviour of a binary semaphore (semaphore initially with s == 1) the pseudocode should be

```
wait(Semaphore s){ 
  s=s-1;
  if (s<0) {
    // add process to queue
    block();
  }
}

signal(Semaphore s){
  s=s+1;
  if (s<=0) {
    // remove process p from queue
    wakeup(p);
  }
}
```